# Evaluate ES6 Array Comprehension String

Tags: javascript, arrays, eval, list-comprehension, ecmascript-6

In ES6, I can use

```
[for(i1 of [0, 1]) for(i2 of [0, 1]) [i1, i2]]
```

and get

```
[[0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1]]
```

I can build a string like

```
str = '[for(i0 of [0, 1]) for(i1 of [0, 1]) [i0, i1]]'
```

or

```
str = '[for(i1 of [0, 1]) for(i2 of [0, 1]) for(i3 of [0, 1]) [i1, i2, i3]]'.
```

How to evaluate/excute such a string?

Comment: The same way how you would evaluate in ES5: eval, new Function..

Comment: You may be able to use the `Traceur.compile` API.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same thing as you would do in ECMAScript 5. Using either `eval`:

```
var arr = eval(str);
```

or `new Function`:

```
var arr = new Function('return' + str)();
```

Comment: Thanks for above.
I should have specified my working environment -- I'm using grunt-traceur-simple for transpiling es6 into es5.
For following code, the transpiler does nothing:
var str = '[for (i of [0,1]) i]'; var arr = eval(str);
And I got 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token for' in my browser.
How can I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.module` or `System.define`.

From http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html:

- `System.module(source, options?)` evaluates the JavaScript code in source to a module (which is delivered asynchronously via a promise).
- `System.set(name, module)` is for registering a module (e.g. one you have created via System.module()).
- `System.define(name, source, options?)` both evaluates the module code in source and registers the result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't know how to use it in my case. I put my code in a [Traceur Repl](http://goo.gl/BD6Hho). How can I evaluate the array comprehension string using traceur?